# How to use jQuery to select this parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a recursive menu where I need the children items to effect the parent. In my example below, how do I add a "selected" class if any of the children have a "selected" class?

```
<ul>
    <li class="administration first">
        <a href="/administration.aspx"><span>Administration</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li class="users first selected"><a href="/administration/users.aspx"><span>Users</span></a></li>
            <li class="forms last"><a href="/administration/forms.aspx"><span>Forms</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="analytics"><a href="/analytics.aspx"><span>Analytics</span></a></li>
    <li class="options"><a href="/options.aspx"><span>Options</span></a></li>
    <li class="system last"><a href="/system.aspx"><span>System</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) method to filter parent list elements.

```
$('li.selected').parents('li').addClass('selected');
```

[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/7TFYL/)

Comment: @Avinash Yes, if that's what you want. BTW, I didn't know such method existed, thanks!